# Group by month and date - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data points as shown below. I have similar data points for each day of the year for every year

```
data1 = {'Date': {1: '01-01-2001',
  2: '01-01-2002',
  3: '01-01-2003',
  4: '01-01-2004',
  5: '01-01-2005',
  6: '01-01-2006',
  7: '01-01-2007',
  8: '01-01-2008',
  9: '01-01-2009',
 10: '01-01-2010'
   },
 'milesrun': {1: '15',
  2: '21',
  3: '19',
  4: '22',
  5: '16',
  6: '13',
  7: '22',
  8: '24',
  9: '17',
 10: '18'}}
```

How can I group by just the month and the date and get the minimum and the maximum values? I need the results in 2 separate dataframes one for minimum and one for maximum.  The resultant data frame should have the output as below

```
mth-date  value
 01-01     13
 01-02     14
 01-03     13
 ............
 ............
 12-29     18
 12-30     16
 12-31     17
```

I was able to extract the month and the date as separate columns but unable to groupby correctly. I am trying to avoid using numpy and see if there is an alternative option

Comment: Is your date format day first or month first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for extract `month`s with `days` and then use `groupby` with aggregate `min`, `max`:

```
#if neccessary convert to datetimes if MM-DD-YYYY
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

dfboth = df['milesrun'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')).agg(['min','max'])
print (dfboth)
      min max
Date         
01-01  13  24
```

Or:

```
dfmin = df['milesrun'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')).min()
dfmax = df['milesrun'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')).max()
```

Comment: I think these are `dayfirst=True` dates.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I should have come up with a better date sample. The initial assumption was correct. it was MM-DD-YYYY.

Comment: @jezrael out of curiosity, if you had multiple columns in the dataset and had to filter using that column, how would you do that? Say for example I had city as an additional column and had to restrict it to one city e.g. New York?

Comment: @rajeev - then need aggregate each column, so instad `dfmin = df['milesrun'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')).min()` need `dfmin = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')).agg({'milesrun':'min', 'city':'first'})`

Comment: @jezrael  to rephrase my question, I was actually looking to add a filter condition like city = 'New York' and only get the results for 'New York'. The solution above will aggregate it by city, right?

Comment: Ok, then need `df = df[df['city'] == 'New York']` before my soltuion, it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).